# .NET + Angular - IIS Server refreshing localhost tab in chrome when request is made from fire fox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

This is bizarre.

I have an angular app served from a .NET MVC project. When I make a request to the backend and complete the response the page refreshes. This only happens in chrome.

Here are the weird variations I've triggered:

1) Serve the app in Chrome, complete request, refreshes page.

2) Serve the app in Chrome, open FF to localhost (so the same page is open in two browsers), trigger the request in FF, request completes. FF does not restart, but the chrome tab does.

3) Serve the app in FF, request does not refresh the page. Open chrome to localhost, make the request from either FF or Chrome, page refreshes.

The .NET route hit just responds with a JsonResult after a file upload. This happens consistently after the completed request hits the subscription. Heres some relevent code:

```
// component
this.myService.uploadFile(formGroup, this.Id).subscribe(result => 
{
  console.log(result);
});

// service
public uploadFile(form: FormGroup, id: number) {
  const options = {
    reportProgress: true,
  };
  const file: File = form.get('file').value;
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('File', file, file.name);
  formData.append('Id', id.toString());

  const request = new HttpRequest('POST', '/file', formData, options);
  return this.http.request(request)
    .pipe<HttpEvent<any>>(
      map((event) => {
      return this.updateProgress(event, form);
     }),
     last()
  );
 }
```

I use this exact same format elsewhere in the app for another file upload component that has different requirements and I dont have any issues.

I only know enough .NET to be dangerous and I'm primarily an SPA developer. If you need some more information about the .NET configuration just ask. I'd really like to track this down.

UPDATE: I found [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8537) that describes a similar event only in chrome. I added `return false` and `$event.preventDefault()` both to the end of the `upload()` function (its the one called by the `(click)` event in the template) and at the end of the subscription scope.

I'm lost.